# how to add jquery to a specific section

Tags: jquery, inline-code

I have this jquery code:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').RainSnow({
        effect_name: 'snow',
        drop_appear_speed: 200,
        drop_falling_speed: 8000,
        wind_direction: 3,
        drop_rotate_angle : '-10deg',
        drop_count_width_height:[[22,22], [14,16], [18,20]],
        drop_left_to_right : false
    });
});
// ]]></script>
```

I have added this script between a fullwidth shortcode in my wordpress page. I want the effect to only show in this section which is a contact form section but even though i have added the script in between the short code it is displaying on the whole of the page.

How do I correctly add the code to get it to display only on the section i want it to?

Comment: You probably have to apply it to just the element you want.  $('body') is the whole page.

Comment: Same as @Shanimal; you should just replace the body tag with your form id...like `$("#myFormId").RainSnow({.....`

Comment: I see, I'm getting there, but although i have added the id="falls" to a dive the effect is still applying to the whole page. http://www.muslimahwebdesign.co.uk/wofwt2

Comment: Have you tried `$("#falls").Rainshow...`

Answer (score -1):

The beginning of the code says to which piece of DOM tree it is going to be applied. You explicitly write "body". Play with this. 
BTW. This looks like after reading jQuery manual on addressing DOM elements you will discover marvellous things.